# Specific font, physics reaction

Tags: fonts

How would one write down this equation in Latex? What kind of font is used for l and nu?

[image: Reaction]

Comment: The default font: `$B \to D^{(*)} \ell \nu_{\ell}$`.

Comment: You can also use [Detexify](http://detexify.kirelabs.org) to find LaTeX symbols.

Comment: Adding to @VáclavPavlík: [How to look up a symbol or identify a math symbol or character?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14/how-to-look-up-a-symbol-or-identify-a-math-symbol-or-character) might help you generally.